# Programmatic Webpack & Jest (ESM): can't resolve module without '.js' file extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm using webpack programmatically, with typescript, ESM, and jest. In a jest test I'm getting errors for not including a `.js` file extension when importing ES modules. For example:

```
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'modulename' in '/path/components'
    Did you mean 'modulename.js'?
    BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'modulename' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
    (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
    The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
    Add the extension to the request.
```

The module in question does indeed have `"type": "module"` set in its `package.json`. I have tried adding `.js` to the import, and it doesn't help.

I'm invoking jest with:

```
node --experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
```

as is recommended [in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) (everything else works except webpack). Note that I have tried with and without `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` (this has helped in other similar circumstances).

Any thoughts on how to get webpack to work? Thanks in advance!

Note: everything was working until it was all converted to ESM! Now only programmatic webpack isn't working.

Webpack config:

```
  {
    entry,
    target: 'web',
    output: {
      path: outputDir,
      filename: '[name].js',
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV as 'development' | 'production' | 'none' | undefined,
    resolve: {
      extensions: [
        '.ts',
        '.tsx',
        '.js',
        '.jsx',
        '.ttf',
        '.eot',
        '.otf',
        '.svg',
        '.png',
        '.woff',
        '.woff2',
        '.css',
        '.scss',
        '.sass',
      ],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|otf|svg|png)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            sourceType: 'unambiguous',
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                {
                  corejs: '3.0.0,',
                  useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                },
              ],
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
            ],
            plugins: [
              'css-modules-transform',
              [
                'babel-plugin-react-scoped-css',
                {
                  include: '.scoped.(sa|sc|c)ss$',
                },
              ],
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sc|c|sa)ss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'scoped-css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/11467#issuecomment-691873586).

Basically, had to add 2 things to the webpack config under `module.rules`:

```
{
  test: /\.m?js/,
  type: "javascript/auto",
},
{
  test: /\.m?js/,
  resolve: {
    fullySpecified: false,
  },
},
```

Comment: I had to add a `$` at the end of the regex. Also, the first rule is not needed.

Comment: did you figure out why the problem happen? why added this config could fix it? @CarlesMitjans

Comment: Where do I place this change? I can not find the webpack.config.js file. I am trying to use JSEncrypt and receive this same error.

Comment: `fullySpecified: false` was enough for me.

Comment: Can I please know how to resolve this in package.json?

Comment: Here is a Webpack documentation page (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#resolvefullyspecified) that explains this behavior. By default `fullySpecified` is set to `true`. It fully ignores `resolve.mainFields` that specifies what `package.json` fields (e.g. `module` & `main`) should be used to resolve package entry point file. If you want the default NodeJS package & module resolution strategy `fullySpecified` field has to be explicitly specified as `false` in your config file.

Answer (score 18):

@nerdlinger answer worked for me.  I had this webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            }
        ],
    }
    ...
}
```

and i changed it to this

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                resolve: {
                  fullySpecified: false,
                }
            }
        ],
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. It worked out fine on my side. I was struggling to use the react-icons