# why the webpack build react app home page stay blank

Tags: reactjs, webpack

when I use webpack 5 to build a react app, the build output project home page stay blank. I did not know where is going wrong, this is my webpack config:

```
  const path = require('path');
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin');
  const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

  module.exports = {
    entry : './src/index.js',
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      compress: true,
      open: true,
      hot: true,
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js','.jsx'],
      alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      },
    },
    output : {
      path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../build') ,
      filename : '[name].js'
    },
    module : {
      rules : [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
          },
          include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../node_modules/js-wheel'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../src')
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/
        },
        {
          test: /\.d\.ts$/,
          loader: 'ignore-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427025/programmatic-webpack-jest-esm-cant-resolve-module-without-js-file-exten
        {
          test: /\.m?js/,
          type: "javascript/auto",
        },
        {
          test: /\.m?js/,
          resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '/public/icons/[name].[ext]'
          }
      }
      ]
    },
    plugins : [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: "public/index.html", to: "index.html" },
          { from: "public/favicon.png", to: "public/favicon.png" },
          { from: "public/manifest.json", to: "public/manifest.json" },
        ],
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css",
      }),
    ]
  };
```

when I open the index page, there is no error. And the page loaded this request:

[image]

why the home page stay blank? what should I do to fix this problem? This is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

const AppView = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(AppView, document.getElementById('root'))
```

and this is part of my `App.js`:

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact render={() => <Redirect to='/index' />} />
                <Route path='/500' component={View500} />
                <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login user={this.props.user} />}/>
                <Route path='/404' component={View404} />
                <Route component={DefaultLayout} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>)
    }
}
```

the react router dom version is `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.1"`. I think it should not be the code problem, because I recently upgrade the webpack version and rewrite the webpack config.I should be the webpack config problem, but I did not figure out where is going wrong.This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="public/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!-- <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" /> -->
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="public/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: what is your index.html, can you pasted it? @liangqicai

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. I changed your `Switch` to `Routes` and your `component` to `element`

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (<Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact render={() => <Redirect to='/index' />} />
            <Route path='/500' element={View500} />
            <Route path='/login' render={(props) => <Login user={this.props.user}
/>}/>
            <Route path='/404' element={View404} />
            <Route element={DefaultLayout} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but still did not fix this problem.@Mizzy

Comment: Are you getting any errors that you can show?

Comment: there is no errors in anywhere, the webpack command running fine with no error output, the home page console has no error output too. @Mizzy

Answer (score 0):

from your `index.html`, I did not found the index js reference, try to add the  js reference like this:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

bundle just the example name of the js, replace with the output name of your webpack config.